# Any way to run / test x86_64 Intel assembly on m1?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, apple-m1

As part of my CS class, I have to run and test Intel x86_64 assembly.

Is there any way to run and or test the assembly on an m1 Mac? It does not have to be very performant, it won't be any complex instructions.

Comment: You should be able to run an x86 VM (more emulation than virtualization) on M1. You can also take advantage of Rosetta 2 (though this may break debugging).

Comment: You could run Linux inside an emulator, perhaps Qemu or even Bochs.  Command-line Linux will be less resource-intensive, or you could SSH into it so the GUI terminal stuff happens natively.  As Margaret points out, ability to debug by single-stepping your asm and watching registers values change is essential.  If that doesn't work with Rosetta2, then it's not usable for learning asm.  (Which is unfortunate because the native MacOS toolchain can make x86-64 binaries from x86-64 asm.  But if you can't debug them, that's not helpful.)